# Question about proof using topological convergence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to work through a proof of the result that convergence in a metric space is equivalent to the fact that every open set containing the limit contains all but finitely many point of the sequence.

There's one subtlety in the backward direction. So let's suppose that every open set containing $p$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. I want to show that $p_n \to p$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Then $B_{\epsilon} (p)$ is both open and contains $p$, so it contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. I want to choose $n_0$ to be the maximal index for which $p_{n_0} \not \in B_{\epsilon} (p)$, and then set $N := n_0 + 1$. Then for any $n \geq N > n_0$, we have $p_n \in B_{\epsilon} (p)$, i.e., $d(p_n, p) <\epsilon$.

The problem I encounter is that $n_0$ may not exist, i.e., $p_n \in B_{\epsilon} (p)$ for all $n$. I don't know if there is a convention for the maximum of an empty set. Is there a way to fix this in the context of the proof? I was thinking I could just say "if there is no such $n_0$, set $n_0 = 0$." Does this work? Is there a better fix?

Comment: In that case just take $N=1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I suppose it makes more sense to pick $1$ than $0$ since it's an index in the sequence. Is that the reasoning?

Comment: Strictly speaking $0$ is not allowed. But $N$ can be any positive integer and you can choose $1$ for definiteness.